# routersploit .rsr extension error message

Tags: python, kali-linux

Im posting this question here after recommendation by stackoverflow

Im trying [routersploit-multi-ip](https://github.com/WongWai95/routersploit-multi-ip) but I am getting the error:

```
./multi_ip_scanner.sh: line 9: scanner_output/192.168.10.2.rsr: No such file or directory
```

I have followed then instructions from this [page](https://github.com/WongWai95/routersploit-multi-ip/blob/master/how-to.pdf) but without success.

Can anyone help me understand the reason for this error?

Thank you